# Second monitor doesn't connect

Tags: release-loki, display, hdmi

I'm running Elementary Os Loki 0.4.1. I wanna connect another monitor to my laptop, but my OS doesn't recognize it. In settings it doesn't even detect that I have another monitor connected (via HDMI).

I've trying shut down the system and getting it back up again, it didn't work. I'm up to date with updates and upgrades too.

I don't know what else to try. If someone could help me, that'll be awesome :)

***UPDATE***
I've been looking and found this:
[Laptop + HDMI external monitor issue?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/6685/laptop-hdmi-external-monitor-issue?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
I tried it , but I don't have the `~/.config/monitors.xml` file. I've search everywhere, even within hidden folder, just nothing.

In my terminal I put tho command `lspci | grep VGA` and the output was:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
```

I tried the command `lspci -nn | grep '\[03'` too, and the output was:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics [8086:191b] (rev 06)

01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM206M [GeForce GTX 965M] [10de:1427] (rev a1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know If you are still around. I never done this but I just gathered info I believe might help you

---

### First

You need to install Nvidia drivers

**Install:**

`$ sudo apt install software-properties-gtk software-properties-common`

**Then use the command:**

`$ sudo ubuntu-drivers list`

You should get something like this (probably different version numbers):

```
nvidia-304
nvidia-340
intel-microcode
nvidia-367
```

**Install** `nvidia-367` (or the version you want, and could be different)

`$ sudo apt install nvidia-367 nvidia-settings`

ref: https://gist.github.com/Jiab77/d3344422ee6d334f284425b558dc572c

---

### Final step

**Open:**

`$ software-properties-gtk`

**Choose** the tab `Additional Drivers`

**Wait** for the  loading list, and then **you should see the recently installed driver**.

**Select** it and **reboot**

[image]

Now, after reboot, **open** `$ nvidia-settings`

**Look after** an entry named `PRIME Profiles`, **select** it and then **choose** the NVIDIA GPU

[image]

**Reboot** again

Done

---

### Additional Info

You can also check and change PRIME using a command

**Install:**

`$ sudo apt install nvidia-prime`

**To check**

`$ sudo prime-select query`

**To select Intel GPU as PRIME**

`$ sudo prime-select intel`

**To select NVIDIA GPU as PRIME**

`$ sudo prime-select nvidia`

ref: https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry for the bit delay. I haven't used linux in a while. 
Thank you very much for your answer. It didn't work exactly, but it worked so that I could find the drivers I needed. 
When I went to the Software&Updates >Additional Drivers, I had one of Nvidia, but didn't work. I also had one called "X.Org X Server (open source", I tried it and it worked.
Thank you very much for the help. Have a really nice day and Merry Christmas and Happy New Year ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have such a problem when my video driver is set to use the internal Intel video card instead of the Nvidia one, and this is because on my hp laptop the HDMI port is on the Nvidia graphics card and there is no access to the internal Intel one. Check out if your configuration is similar

Comment: I believe I have that same problem, and I'm still new to the elementary, so could you tell me where I can find those configurations, please?

Comment: ok, can you use the Terminal application, copy and  paste there the following code `lspci | grep VGA` , press Enter and leave a comment with the output?

Comment: I'm so sorry for the delay, but i didn't had my computer with me until now
The output of the command is `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having a problem with display drivers you can try: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Or if there are any other problems with drivers or packages during the boot run: `sudo dpkg --configure -a`