# Second Display not Detected

Tags: display, release-hera

I'm running Elementary OS 2.1 Hera. System is AsRock B450M Pro4 with Ryzen 5 2400g CPU, with the Vega graphics.

Booting up, the system only recognises one display. I have two monitors connected, one to the VGA port, the other via HDMI. The system defaults to the VGA monitor. It will use the HDMI if that is the only one connected. However, it will not detect the second monitor when connected.

I have tried booting with the monitors plugged in, or plugging them in after boot-up. However, still only detects one monitor. Works fine in Windows.

Any help appreciated. Please go easy on me. I have not the most tech savvy.  Thank you!

Comment: Please read this thread: [Laptop + HDMI external monitor issue?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/6685/laptop-hdmi-external-monitor-issue)